# How to keep iPad from dropping out from iPhone's hotspot?

Tags: iphone, ipad, tethering

My iPad mini only has wifi and so I would usually tether 3G connection from my iPhone 4S. In fact, I tether connection from my iPhone to my other devices too such as my laptop.

However, it seems that my iPad keeps dropping out from the tethered connection whenever it goes to sleep. I have searched on the internet for a solution on this, and one of those includes refreshing a website in Safari on my iPad every 10 to 15mins to keep the connection alive. I thought this is rather silly. It is ironic because my Surface tablet can connect persistently to my iPhone's hotspot, but I'm facing problem with Apple's own iPad.

Is there any way to keep my iPad's connection to my iPhone's hotspot persistent such that it doesn't just go away when it goes to sleep?

Both devices are running on iOS 7.

Comment: a long term Apple user and advocate, with tens of kEUR on my bill, I will be considering other options in near future; this is just one reason in the army of issues that frquently make me waste my life on my iPhone (6 Plus on 9.2.3 crrently)

Comment: @ErikAllik it has been almost 3 years since I posted this questions. I haven't had an answer to this problem yet.